# Why do some outputs have a zero value and no address?

Tags: blockchain, output

What does it mean when an output has a value of zero and no address?  I'm looking at some fairly recent transactions, and I don't understand what this means.  Here's an example: https://blockchain.info/block-height/348120?format=json.

You can find the transactions quickly if you search that page for `"value":0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The outputs have no address because they are data-carrying outputs.

```
  {
     "spent":false,
     "tx_index":80899271,
     "type":0,
     "value":0,
     "n":3,
     "script":"6a144153435249424553504f4f4c5245474953544552"
  }
```

The `script` argument is the serialized equivalent of

```
OP_RETURN 4153435249424553504f4f4c5245474953544552
```

(The hex decodes to "ASCRIBESPOOLREGISTER")

`OP_RETURN` means that all attempts to spend this output will fail. This can't be spent, so there's no point in putting money in it - it would just be lost.

Comment: You've answered the question, but it still doesn't make any sense to me.  What does it mean to be a data-carrying output?  Why is this output even created in the first place?

Comment: @mrp It's called a data-carrying output because it could contain any small piece of data: Bitcoin doesn't look at it. As for the meaning of this specific piece of data, I have no idea. Google searches aren't particularly informative.

Comment: @mrp It's just a compromise where data can be validated and saved in the Blockchain while not taxing the network with perfunctory bloat